# Issue with Camera in docker with ubuntu:arm64v8:20.04 base image

Tags: docker, gstreamer, arm64

OS: aarch64
Camera: v4l2

Hi,
i'm currently trying to get my Camera running in docker with gstreamer. When i use the Base Image: `resin/rpi-raspbian:stretch` and try it with the gstreamer Command to test the Camera: `gst-launch-1.0 --gst-debug-level=2 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! video/x-raw,format=RGB,width=640,height=512,framerate=60/1 ! fakesink` it works perfectly fine. But for my Project i need an Ubuntu Base Image so i changed the base image to: `arm64v8/ubuntu:20.04` installation works fine, but i try to run the same gstreamer cmd it's getting an Internal Data Stream Error. The only difference i found out when using debug level 4 was with the Formats.
Raspian Stretch:

> v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1150:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list: got 7 format(s):
> 0:00:00.948217101    24   0x111af0 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1156:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:   YU12
> 0:00:00.948381217    24   0x111af0 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1156:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:   NV12
> 0:00:00.948543303    24   0x111af0 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1156:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:   YV12 (emulated)
> 0:00:00.948712575    24   0x111af0 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1156:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:   BGR3 (emulated)
> 0:00:00.948881431    24   0x111af0 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1156:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:   RGB3 (emulated)
> 0:00:00.949050964    24   0x111af0 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1156:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:   ....
> 0:00:00.949211539    24   0x111af0 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1156:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:   Y16

Ubuntu arm64:

> v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1201:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:v4l2src0:src got 4 format(s):
> 0:00:00.102641022    18   0x55556fecc0 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1205:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:v4l2src0:src   YU12
> 0:00:00.102685032    18   0x55556fecc0 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1205:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:v4l2src0:src   NV12
> 0:00:00.102717272    18   0x55556fecc0 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1205:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:v4l2src0:src   ....
> 0:00:00.102750710    18   0x55556fecc0 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1205:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:v4l2src0:src   Y16

On Ubuntu it than raises an Error because its taking a Complete different format(I420).
Hope somebody can help me out, i'm getting really frustrated, didn't found anyone else having this type of issue.

Comment: why do you need Ubuntu base image instead of raspbian - can't you extend the raspbian base image to install what you need?

Comment: maybe explain your boss that it takes much more time and effort to figure out which lib-s are missing or having incompatible version, than to use raspbian and install there whatever you need from Ubuntu...

Comment: Thanks for your advice but that was not really my Question in this Thread...

Comment: So i figured out the Issue.
Add run-time environment to enable libv4l2
The library has started preventing a lot of interesting use cases,
like CREATE_BUFS, DMABuf, usage of TRY_FMT. As the libv4l2 is totally
inactive and not maintained, we decided to disable it. As a convenience
we added a run-time environment that let you enable it for testing.

GST_V4L2_USE_LIBV4L2=1

This of course only works if you have enabled libv4l2 at build time.
If you built in docker just add ENV GST_V4L2_USE_LIBV4L2=1 at the end of the Dockerfile if you run on  local machine: export GST_V4L2_USE_LIBV4L2=1

Comment: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-good/-/issues/644